# Symfony2: classes.php

Tags: symfony

Symfony2 compiles all classes into single cached file called classes.php which is very hard to debug. Is it possible to turn off this feature in dev mode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/debugging.html
More about :

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
// $kernel->loadClassCache();
$kernel->handle(Request::createFromGlobals())->send();
```

Comment: in other words: just comment out the ``$kernel->loadClassCache();`` in ``app_dev.php``